# No realiza la acción "Llamada" al pulsar sobre "ImageButton" al concederle los permisos (Android 6+)

Tags: java, javascript, android, permisos

Tengo un problema y es que quiero que me realice una llamada al pulsar sobre una "ImageButton" pero no lo hace con el código nuevo.

Código que tenía antes para realizar llamadas:

```
icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0000000"));
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return;
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }
});
```

El problema de ese código es que no me pedía los permisos en Android 6+, así que lo cambie por este:

```
final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 10;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // PERMISO CONCEDIDO, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
                } else {
                    // PERMISO DENEGADO
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

        icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Aquí ya está concedido, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
                }else{
                    // Aquí lanzamos un dialog para que el usuario confirme si permite o no el realizar llamadas
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Y con este si me pide los permisos para realizar la llamada, pero no llama, no hace nada al pulsar sobre la ImageButton una vez concedido el permiso.

ManifestActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn1;
    ImageButton btn2;
    ImageButton btn3;
    ImageButton btn4;
    ImageButton btn5;
    ImageButton icon_des1;
    ImageButton icon_des2;
    ImageButton icon_des3;
    ImageButton icon_des4;
    ImageButton icon_des5;
    ImageButton icon_des6;

    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 10;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // PERMISO CONCEDIDO, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
                } else {
                    // PERMISO DENEGADO
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.text_des);

        btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        icon_des1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des1);
        icon_des2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des2);
        icon_des3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des3);
        icon_des4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des4);
        icon_des5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des5);
        icon_des6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon_des6);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(boton1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton2);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton3);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent boton5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                startActivity(boton5);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent icon_des4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main6Activity_gmail.class);
                startActivity(icon_des4);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

        icon_des5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Aquí ya está concedido, procede a realizar lo que tienes que hacer
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
                }else{
                    // Aquí lanzamos un dialog para que el usuario confirme si permite o no el realizar llamadas
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                }
            }
        });

        icon_des6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.es");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:112"));
startActivity(i);
```

Luego de verificar que hay permisos declaras el `Intent` pero no lo llamas, por eso no hace nada.

Comment: Listo! Solucionado, se me pasó por alto, muchas gracias !

Comment: Un saludo @UserNameYo  exito!